# Expect script continues to run even the expect does not match anything

Tags: bash, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn ssh admin@10.10.10.10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect "5555:"
send "$password\n"
expect "% "
send "exit\n"
```

No matter what value wrote on expect "5555:" this command still working and I have ssh connection.

Comment: This is a legit question, but seems to me like it might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to achieve? There might be better ways.

Comment: @DanZaltsman : But I guess it is waiting for a couple of seconds, until it continues running?

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). Its defaults are more reasonable. And you can write Expect with shell scripts.

Comment: After you `send "exit\r"`, you should `expect eof` to allow the ssh connection to gracefully close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set a timeout and an action upon the timeout:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 5 
spawn ssh admin@10.10.10.10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect {
   "5555:"  { }
   timeout { exit 2 }
}
send "$password\n"
expect "% "
send "exit\n"
```

---

Some extra info: the default timeout is 10 seconds. While `expect`ing something, if the pattern has not been seen after `$timeout` seconds, the `expect` command *without* a "timeout" pattern simply returns and the script continues.